# How to create open page spread appearance in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am working on a project using InDesign and I need to give it an effect such as an open magazine, for example.

I saw this video and so many projects like this one: [DIESEL FW13 MAIN VISUAL GUIDELINES](https://www.behance.net/gallery/10632927/DIESEL-FW13-MAIN-VISUAL-GUIDELINES) and I just want to know how can I get this kind of effect.

[image]

I know in Photoshop you can do it with so actions, but I am really new with Adobe InDesign and I don't know much about it.

Comment: `Object > Effects > Gradient feather`

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, is there any guide for the steps?

Answer (score 2):

Info of InDesign's transparency effects are here: [Transparency: Working with Effects in Adobe InDesign CS6](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/adding-transparency-effects.html#transparency_effects)

And there's a bit of a walk-through here: [InDesign Help / 
Adding transparency effects](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1873032&seqNum=2)

To simulate the shading down the inner margins of the page, you could draw a rectangular frame from the top to the bottom of your page, and position it so it sits a little on the inner margins of both pages of the spread (if using facing pages) or down the centre of your page (if not using facing pages).

In the 'Effects' panel change the blending mode from 'normal' to 'multiply', and change the transparency if you need to. Then in the 'fx' drop-down menu choose 'directional feather' because you will want to soften the left and right edges of your rectangle.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I would add to your Answer that adding this effect must be in the very top layer of your document to ensure that the gradient effect will apply not only on the white background pages but also onto any artwork and text may appear in the page.

Comment: Thanks! but is it possible the line which separate the facing pages in InDesign make it thinner?

Comment: I don't think so @Amd, but the spine line doesn't actually appear in any printed or exported output. If you create a PDF of the spread, you won't see any line. While working inside InDesign though, I believe there will always be the line.

Comment: @apex is correct. If you want to have include a line for your finished product,  insert a line of your choice down the very center, then export the pages as "spreads" rather than "pages" upon completion. This keeps it all on one page when you export.